# Android project is not able to run. Showing errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Everything was installed correctly. I am using Windows XP ,JDK 7.5 , Eclipse 4.2.
AVD is also setup correctly

When i run project it does not display it in a Virtual device.
This is the error I get:

```
[2012-08-05 11:49:09 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-08-05 11:49:09 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: E:\Documents and Settings\chamara\.android\avd\Gingabread1.avd/sdcard.img
[2012-08-05 11:49:09 - Emulator] ko:Snapshot storage already in use: E:\Documents and Settings\chamara\.android\avd\Gingabread1.avd/snapshots.img
```

[Image 1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/anroidhelp5.jpg)
[image2](http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/3056/anroidhelp5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your emulator exited rather ungracefully and left everything locked up.

Look in your `E:\Documents and Settings\chamara\.android\avd\Gingabread1.avd` directory and delete any directory that ends with `.lock`.  That should allow you to start up your virtual device again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the exact problem is, but try removing your SD card and reboot eclipse...

Comment: I'm running from emulator ( virtual device )

Comment: @cmsgun - Try removing the *virtual* SD card!